# TCP socket server to handle multiple clients connections concurrently using spring integration

Tags: sockets, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have been working on creating TCP socket server using spring integration, with the reference from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290834/how-to-create-a-tcp-connection-in-spring-boot-to-accept-connections?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I am able to setup socket connection.

My requirement has 4 clients which establish socket connection with the server.
How can I handle concurrent requests from all the 4 clients. what changes has to be done at TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.

Could someone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concern isn't clear. The `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` (any `AbstractConnectionFactory`) uses an `Executor` to distribute work from the established connections. And by default it is like:

```
if (this.taskExecutor == null) {
    this.privateExecutor = true;
    this.taskExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}
```

So, this says to us that indeed all the 4 clients are going to be handled on the server concurrently.

Comment: My concern is to handle multiple client connections concurrently. so as per your comments, the TcpNetServerConnectionFactory by default handles concurrent connections without any need to implement executor service?

Comment: Correct. You always can inject any other `TaskExecutor` to the `ConnectionFactory`

Comment: ThankYou for your answer.Appreciate it!!