# How can I use a session or request-scoped bean in a component annotated bean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, tcpsocket

In a former question [How to create a working TCP Server socket in spring boot and how to handle the incoming message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394292/how-to-create-a-working-tcp-server-socket-in-spring-boot-and-how-to-handle-the-i/64394849?noredirect=1#comment113928149_64394849)
I was stuck in some problems with spring integration and handling a TCP socket connection.
That problem is solved, but a new one appered, unfortunately...
I got my message from the client - so far so good - but now I tried to use the allready existing business logic to process the message like this:

**This is a class to handle an incoming socket message. Implemented via spring integration**

```
import homebrew.something.MessageProcessor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Log4j2
@Component
@MessageEndpoint
public class ClientSocketHandler {
    
    @Autowired
    private MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
    public byte[] handleMessage(byte[] msg) {
        
        byte[] msgToSend = messageProcessor.processMessage(msg);
        
        return msgToSend;
    }
}
```

**This is a regular transfer object class bound to a HTTP session**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;

@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ASimpleTransferObject {
    
    // Some fields, 
    // some getters and
    // some setters
    
}
```

**Here we got our service to handle the incoming message from the TCP socket**

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Log4j2
@Service
public class MessageProcessor {
    
    @Autowired
    private ASimpleTransferObject transferObject;
    
    public byte[] processMessage(byte[] msg) {
        
        // Do something with the message
        
        return message;
        
    }
}
```

If I am sending a message from client to server, this Exception is thrown:

```
ERROR org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection - Exception sending message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=XXXX, ip_connectionId=view-localhost:XXXXX:YYYYY:AAAA-BBBB-CCCC, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=fd33bdd9-1af1-051f-3106-3f08af7bdd16, ip_hostname=view-localhost, timestamp=87236587436545}]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1b067e83]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.transferObject': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:111) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:104) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:522) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:493) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:127) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.onMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:105) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:216) [spring-integration-ip-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.transferObject': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:675) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at homebrew.something.ASimpleTransferObject$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$45c84ec3.getSessionKey(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    ....
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(CustomizableTraceInterceptor.java:256) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:129) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:55) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:386) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:375) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:171) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:156) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:637) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.fallbackToInvokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:630) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInvokeExceptionAndFallbackToExpressionIfAny(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:614) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:585) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:477) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:355) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:55) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:675) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at homebrew.something.ASimpleTransferObject$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$45c84ec3.getSessionKey(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    ....
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(CustomizableTraceInterceptor.java:256) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ....
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:129) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:55) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:386) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:375) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:171) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:156) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:637) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.fallbackToInvokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:630) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInvokeExceptionAndFallbackToExpressionIfAny(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:614) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:585) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:477) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:355) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
```

I allready tried to put a RequestContextListener to my spring configuration

```
@Bean
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

but that didn't realy help. The same Exception was thrown again.

Is there a solution for that problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not possible since TCP connection is fully not related to HTTP connection. We have that session context, when we deal with an HTTP connection initiated from the HTTP client and when we have a session management in our HTTP server, e.g. Srvlet Container.

The TCP connection is initiated fully different way and there is no hook to take an HTTP session from the manager since there is no an HTTP request tied with that session.

You probably need to learn more about HTTP and its session state...

The main point that TCP connection is done in a thread which knows nothing about HTTP and we can initialize session scope only when we do an interaction with HTTP thread and some client session token in the request.

I'm not sure how to help you, but what you are looking for is just not possible and you can't use that session scope outside of HTTP requests. You need to rethink your business logic to something else which will fit your TCP request already.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the detailed reply. No, I think, I know how the sessions are working in Spring, but I thought there could be a bridge or transformer to handle this specific  problem. Now, I know it better and I will think over the conceptional design to find a working solution.