# Nginx blocks ServerSocket communication in Java

Tags: java, nginx, ssl

I have a ServerSocket that MUST uses SSL to communication, i configured SSL in Nginx. When i want to connect to `ServerSocket` the line `System.out.println("Connected to server")` printed but line `System.out.println("New Client Connected")` does NOT.

Server:

```
 new Thread(() -> {
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8085);
            java.net.Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("New Client Connected");

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

            int i;
            while ((i = input.read()) != -1)
                System.out.print(i + " ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
```

Client:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("my.host.name"), 8083)) {
        System.out.println("Connected to server");

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        printWriter.println("Heelo from client");
        printWriter.flush();

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name java-app;
    listen 8083 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /location/to/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /location/to/privkey.pem;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
    }
}

server {
    server_name localhost-server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /location/to/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /location/to/privkey.pem;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
    }
}
```

I mapped my public 8083 port, to my local 8085 port.

```
my.host.name:8083 -> localhost:8085
```

But when i disable Nginx at all and try to connect to `ServerSocket` directly by below code, every thing goes RIGHT. Notice the port now is `8085`

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("my.host.name"), 8085)) {
    System.out.println("Connected to server");

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    printWriter.println("Heelo from client");
    printWriter.flush();

} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Comment: Locally you are not using SSL, so your code works. When using Nginx you are using SSL, so your Client code must be adapted to perform the handshake. See this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/sample-code-illustrating-secure-socket-connection-client-and-server.htm#JSSEC-GUID-AA1C27A1-2CA8-4309-B281-D6199F60E666.

Comment: i'm not connecting locally, i'm just connecting directly, (by STOPPING nginx)

Comment: The point is that when you stop Nginx you are accessing without SSL. When going through Nginx 8083 (SSL) you must perform the handshake on client side. You can easily perform a simple test, by opening another non SSL port on Nginx and see it works. You must perform the SSL Handshake on client side as it is exemplified here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/sample-code-illustrating-secure-socket-connection-client-and-server.htm#JSSEC-GUID-AA1C27A1-2CA8-4309-B281-D6199F60E666